# O programa não consegue chamar o método set de outra classe, mesmo com ela instanciada

Tags: java

Quando vou chamar o método `setNomedoMetodo()` em outra classe, mesmo com ela instanciada, aparece:

> The method setNaipe(String[]) is undefined for the type Baralho.

Eu não consigo colocar um valor nesse método. E também não consigo misturar as cartas. Segue um trecho do código:

Classe Carta

```
public class Carta {
    private String[] naipe;
    private String[] nome;

    //Métodos especiais
    public String[] getNaipe() {
        return naipe;
    }
    public void setNaipe(String[] naipe) {
        this.naipe = naipe;
    }
    public String[] getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String[] nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

}
```

Classe Baralho

```
package Jogo;

import java.util.Random;

public class Baralho {
    Carta[] cartas = new Carta[52];
    String[] naipes = {"Copas", "Espada", "Ouros", "Paus"};
    String[] nomes = {"As", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"};
    String coringa;
    Random aleatorio = new Random();
    public Baralho() {
        int cont = 0;
        for (String naipe : naipes) {
            for (String nome : nomes) {
                Carta cartas = new Carta();
                this.setNaipe(naipes);
                this.setNome(nomes);
                this.cartas[cont] = cartas;
                this.embaralha(naipes);
                cont++;
            }
            this.setNaipe(coringa);
        }
        System.out.println(cartas);//Teste
    }
    public void embaralha(String[] carta) {
        aleatorio.naipes();
    }
    public void daCarta() {
        for (int i = 0; i < cartas.length; i++) {
            if (cartas[0] == null) {
                break;
            }else {
                System.out.println(cartas[0]);
            }
        }
    }
    public boolean temCarta() {
        boolean TouF = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < cartas.length; i++) {
            if (cartas[i] != null) {
                TouF = false;
            }else {
                TouF = true;
            }
        }
        return TouF;
    }
    public void imprime() {
        for (int i = 0; i < cartas.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(cartas[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Adicione a classe baralho completa.

Comment: Adicionei a classe completa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O método `setNaipe()` nao existe na classe `Baralho`, chamando da forma abaixo:

```
this.setNaipe(naipes);
```

você está tentando chamar o método como se ele existisse na classe `Baralho`. Se o objetivo é chamar da classe `Cartas`, você deve chamar o método a partir de alguma instancia desta classe:

```
for (String naipe : naipes) {
    for (String nome : nomes) {
        Carta cartas = new Carta();
        cartas.setNaipe(naipes);
        cartas.setNome(nomes);
        this.cartas[cont] = cartas;
        this.embaralha(naipes);
        cont++;
    }
```

Nao entendi o objetivo da linha `this.setNaipe(coringa);` logo abaixo do laço acima, mas essa linha tambem não irá funcionar pelo mesmo motivo acima.

Comment: Muito obrigado, ajudou bastante.  A linha this.setNaipe(coringa) era para adicionar a carta coringa. Mas quanto ao Método embaralha, eu não consigo misturar as cartas.

Comment: @MarcosPauloS.Rezende ai ja e outra duvida diferente. Melhor fazer outra pergunta